# React Redux Toolkit with Electron.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, electron, redux-toolkit

I am coding a normal web app with react and redux toolkit and i want to eventually make it into a desktop app with electron, i have solved the react part but it seems redux is not working, i have set up the store provider on the index.js of the react app as i always have but i am guessing these is another way for electron perhaps?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import store from './store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
          .....
          .....
          .....
      </Provider>
      
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already solved it?

I didn't find anything particularly strange in your code.
Please check the path of the redux store.
I've worked with react + electron + typescript before.

Share the **index.tsx** file in the **src** folder inside the react folder.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { store } from './store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

// ↓ You can ignore the code below.
declare global {
  interface Window {
    Kakao: any;
    Naver: any;
  }
}
// ↑ You can ignore the code below.

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/measuring-performance/
reportWebVitals();
```

Hope this helps you!